# sqlldr syntax error

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

```
oracle@tdc2mdb07> cat rsm.ctl
**************************************************
LOAD DATA
infile '/tmp/20181012_bkp.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE ASSET_ODS.ROADSIDE_MESSAGE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
RM_ID                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(12),
RM_COMMS_DATE                                      TIMESTAMP(3),
RM_DETECTION_DATE                                  TIMESTAMP(3),
RM_TSMC_ID                                NOT NULL NUMBER(3),
RM_CHANNEL                                NOT NULL NUMBER(1),
RM_SEQUENCE_NO                                     NUMBER(10),
RM_MESSAGE_CLASS                                   NUMBER(3),
RM_MESSAGE_TYPE                                    NUMBER(5),
RM_RAW_DATA                                        RAW(1200),
RM_STATUS                                 NOT NULL NUMBER(1),
RM_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_STATUS                          VARCHAR2(2),
RM_TOLLING_SEGMENT_ID                              NUMBER(3),
RM_ASSET_ID                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)
)

oracle@tdc2mdb07> sqlldr \'/ as sysdba\' rsm.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Mon Oct 15 10:04:06 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 7.
Expecting "," or ")", found "NOT".
RM_ID                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(12),
                                          ^
```

Comment: fixed by editing the control file as below. Now a new error,

Comment: LOAD DATA
infile '/tmp/rsm_dat_20181012_bkp.txt'
APPEND INTO TABLE ASSET_ODS.ROADSIDE_MESSAGE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
RM_ID,
RM_COMMS_DATE,
RM_DETECTION_DATE,
RM_TSMC_ID,
RM_CHANNEL,
RM_SEQUENCE_NO,
RM_MESSAGE_CLASS,
RM_MESSAGE_TYPE,
RM_RAW_DATA RAW(1200),
RM_STATUS,
RM_SEQUENCE_NUMBER_STATUS,
RM_TOLLING_SEGMENT_ID,
RM_ASSET_ID
)

Comment: oracle@tdc2mdb07> sqlldr \'/ as sysdba\' rsm_bkp.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Mon Oct 15 11:08:29 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

SQL*Loader-261: illegal use of TERMINATED BY for RAW field

Comment: If you have an update to your code **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it), do **not** post code or additional important information as comments. To format the text select it, then click on the `{}` button when you [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL*Loader-00100 to SQL*Loader-03120](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/SQL-Loader-00100.htm#ERRMG-GUID-538A8B3F-0E15-4092-82FD-DEB70FDF9A6D)

> **SQL*Loader-00261:** illegal use of TERMINATED BY for RAW field
>
> **Cause:**
>   The TERMINATED BY option cannot be used for loading data of type RAW
>   from the data file. The only exception is when loading RAW data from
>   LOBFILES. In that case, you may specify the TERMINATED BY EOF option.
>
> **Action:** Remove the TERMINATED BY option from the RAW field in the
>   SQL*Loader control file.